# C loop with undetermined number

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I've been stumped for the past few days trying to modify my current code to be able to input an undetermined number of students.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char StudentName[100];
   float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
   int students, exams;

   for (students = 0; students < 5; students++)
   {
      Sum = 0.0;
      printf("Enter Student Name \n");
      scanf("%s", StudentName);

      for (exams = 0; exams < 3; exams++)
      {
         printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
         scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
         Sum += ExamValue;
      }
      Avg = Sum / 3.0;
      printf("Average for %s is %f\n", StudentName, Avg);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

As it is now, I have to manually input the amount of students. Does anyone know how I can modify this code in order to enter an undetermined amount of students? I'm starting to think that it is impossible to do and maintain the integrity of the rest of the code. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Ask the user how many students there are, and use that value as your loop upper limit.

Comment: `scanf` to get the number of students and then `malloc` to allocate enough memory to hold the students. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Has your teacher introduced you to arrays yet?

Comment: Always check return value of scanf. Debugging any scanf-containing code without having that return value check is waste of time.

Comment: Also, it's generally much more robust, if you use for example fgets to read entire line, then use sscanf to parse numbers out of it. Then you can also easily have empty line or "quit" or whatever to mean end of input.

Comment: `malloc` is not required here

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like `while (stillAdding)` instead of the `for` loop, and prompt the user with `Enter student name or QUIT to stop`, or even `Would you like to enter a new student [Y/n]`. You'd modify the `stillAdding` variable accordingly. In short, you leave it up to the user to specify when they want to stop inputting more data.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the number of users before the `for` and then use that number as upper bounds of the for. Something like this:

```
int students, exams, nr;
printf("Enter Student Number \n");
scanf("%d", &nr);
for (students = 0; students < nr; students++)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user whether there are more students per loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char StudentName[100];
    float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
    int students, exams;
    char stop;

    for (;;)
    {
        Sum = 0.0;
        printf("Enter Student Name \n");
        scanf(" %s", StudentName);
        for (exams = 0; exams < 3; exams++)
        {
            printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
            scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
            Sum += ExamValue;
        }
        Avg = Sum / 3.0;
        printf("Average for %s is %f\n", StudentName, Avg);

        puts("More students?(Y/N)");
        scanf("%*[^yYnN]%c%*[^\n]%*c", &stop); // read one of 'y', 'Y', 'n', 'N', then discard that line, including '\n'.
        if (stop == 'N' || stop == 'n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can prompt the user to supply the number of inputs. Once the user tells you how many inputs will be given, then you can simply use a for loop to read that many inputs

Comment: click " enter image description here" to view a screen captures of the code